# Unable to access the jenkins through publi-ip and port

Tags: jenkins

I already install jenkins in the instance but i am unable to fetch the jenkins through browser using the public ip and port no. . I followed all the installation process accordingly

After Installed the jenkins i can see in my instance jenkins is in running state but i am unable to fetch through 8080port.

In ec2 instance also i changed securty group to all traffic.

Already followed all the necessary steps but unable to access the jenkins through port 8080.

[Jenkins running in instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPJAE.png)

[Unable to access the jenkins through ip and port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wtNh.png)

Please suggest any solution to solve this.

I am trying to access the jenkins through ip and port but unable to access that.

Comment: if you curl localhost:8080 from within the instance, do you see that the site is up? If so, you can be assured that Jenkins is running, and this is a problem with accessing the instance from your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the issue was resolved i was facing the issues because of incorrectly creation of EC2 Instance.